# How do I change the default email client to Gmail in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, gmail, email-client

Does anyone know how to add or change the default email client in Internet Explorer 8/9? I'd like to have mailto links open with Gmail, much like Firefox is capable of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK it can't be done easily. you can set it to a program and use gmail, or use a reghack like this
http://www.questionbin.com/blogcomment/How-to-set-Gmail-as-your-default-client-in-Windows.html

IE might have addons to do it too, but their addons are few and crap.

Answer (score -3):

In Firefox go into Gmail and then in your browser bar enter this:

javascript:window.navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto","https://
mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s","Gmail")

That will make Gmail the default in Firefox.